# How to understand the different camera convention in Computer Vision and Computer Graphics

Tags: graphics, computer-vision

Recently when I try to reconstruct some RGBD images into the original point cloud in world coordinate, I find that it involves the camera convention problem. In some frameworks, such as three.js, WebGL, OpenGL, the camera points to the negative z-direction. While in some other framework, they may have some different choices.

So given a depth image or a pair of RGBD image, how can I know the camera convention without knowing its generating process (only focus on rendered images)? And to be honest, I'm still a bit confused about the camera convention, why it will influence? In my opinion, the original point cloud should have a unique coordinate in the world frame. What on earth will different camera conventions cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the camera maker doesn't tell the formula in use, it is a simple matter to compare the depth of some background and foreground pixels on a sample image to discover it. Then it is up to you to flip the depths to the appropriate convention.

As the processing algorithm that you will use may depend on this convention, you'd better know it otherwise they will just fail or return scrambled results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! So the camera convention will only influence the step from camera coordinate to image coordinate? (E.g. z-flip & y-flip) Will it influence extrinsic transformation (between world coordinate and camera coordinate)? Thanks again for your help!